# Inkscape drawing changed from red to gray when opening in k40 whisper

Tags: inkscape

I'm using Inkscape and K40 Whisper together. When creating geometry in Inkscape it does not stay red after opening in K40 Whisper.
Why is it changed to gray?

Comment: SORRY, I HAVE KLAZOMANIA!

Comment: Please consider giving more detail, so users can help you better. Are all elements always changing color? Is only red affected? What happens in your setup if you copy some elements and make them blue? What do you see when you save in K40 Whisper and then open in Inkskape again? Is the color really gone or visible again?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To be red in an useful way in k40W SVG objects should be simple paths with single stroke, no fill, no Inkscape effects. I guess your greyed red objects are something else and k40W tells to you they cannot be cut. I believe your color is not too far away from pure red RGB(255,0,0), but that's, of course, also possible.

People here and an automate named "Community Bot" have waited some useful details beyond those useless complaints you have written. You have not bothered even to insert a maximally simple problematic SVG file example. I will vote to close your question as soon as I collect the needed reputation for voting.